# Get notified when friends come online in Google Plus

Tags: google-plus

Is there anyway to set up Google Plus so that you get notified when friends in your Circles come online in Google Plus?

If this is of any importance, I have a Google account without Gmail.

This will primarily be so that I can do a Hangout with someone and not be forced to check Hangouts to see if they are online.

Comment: How do you define "come online in Google Plus"? Do you want to be notified when one of your friends open a browser and goes to plus.google.com?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal They are online when I go to hangouts and there is the green dot in the lower left hand corner of their profile photo.

Comment: If you use an XMPP client, you could set it up to notify you of contacts coming online, but I don’t think it’s possible through the web interface directly.